# Html, thymleaf radiobutton th:field="" fails if data is null

Tags: html, input, radio-button, thymeleaf

I´d like to autofill receipt data. If my receipt is not null it should pick the right gender to a radio button with thymeleaf. There are no errors if the receipt is not null, but if receipt is null the errors are thrown

```html
<div class="form-group">
            <div id="genderReceipt">
                <label for="genderMaleReceipt" class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="genderReceipt" id="genderMaleReceipt" value="MALE" th:field="*{receipt.gender}"/>
                    Herr
                </label>
                <label for="genderFemaleReceipt" class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="genderReceipt" id="genderFemaleReceipt" value="FEMALE" th:field="*{receipt.gender}"/>
                    Frau
                </label>
            </div>
            <label for="genderReceipt" class="error" style="display: none;"> Bitte gib eine Anrede an.</label>
</div>
```

The result should be like: if receipt == null both are unchecked... if receipt != null the right gender is checked

error log says:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'receipt' available as request attribute

Comment: Please post long logs at some pastebin site because it is hard too read the question otherwise. Alos, without having a http://www.sscce.org/ of the problem, there will likely nobaody be able to help. You show a HTML-template snippet but the logs show Java errors. It is impossible to know where the error lies with the information you provide.

Comment: i think the error only occurs if the receipt object is null. In thymeleaf its possible to say 
th:value="${ object } != null ? 'ok' : 'not ok' " but I find no solution for input type radio and th:field=...

Answer (score 0):

My Solution for this problem is to duplicate the code and insert th:if statements like here in the example

```html
<div th:if="${receipt} == null">
                <label for="genderFemaleReceipt" class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="genderReceipt" id="genderMaleReceipt" value="MALE" />
                    Herr
                </label>
                <label for="genderFemaleReceipt" class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="genderReceipt" id="genderFemaleReceipt" value="FEMALE" />
                    Frau
                </label>
            </div>
            <div th:if="${receipt} != null">
                <label for="genderFemaleReceipt" class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="genderReceipt" id="genderMaleReceipt" value="MALE" th:field="*{receipt.gender}"/>
                    Herr
                </label>
                <label for="genderFemaleReceipt" class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="genderReceipt" id="genderFemaleReceipt" value="FEMALE" th:field="*{receipt.gender}"/>
                    Frau
                </label>
            </div>
```

I know thats not best practice ;( but i didn´t know a other way to do it.

Comment: Intializing the gender attribute with empty string in controller is good enough, instead of having duplicate code.